# Replace text with a short script in PHP file

Tags: php

Is there a simple way to change all 3 instances of the word **brocken** (in my directory of images) in this php script by means of a form? That way any time I need to create a new .php file I can simply type and hit enter!
Please give me some pointers on what I need to do with regards to setting up the script and button.

```
 <?php 

  // Image extensions
  $image_extensions = array("png","jpg","jpeg","gif");

  // Target directory
  $dir = 'images/brocken';
  if (is_dir($dir)){

  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
  $count = 1;

  // Read files
  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

  if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

   // Thumbnail image path
   $thumbnail_path = "images/brocken/thumbnail/".$file;

   // Image path
  $image_path = "images/brocken/".$file;

  $thumbnail_ext = pathinfo($thumbnail_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $image_ext = pathinfo($image_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

etc etc

Comment: I don't follow. What have forms got to do with string replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
<?php 

  // Image extensions
  $image_extensions = array("png","jpg","jpeg","gif");

  // Target directory
  $dir = 'images/brocken';
  if (is_dir($dir)){

  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
  $count = 1;

  // Read files
  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

  if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

   // Thumbnail image path
   $thumbnail_path = "{$dir}/thumbnail/{$file}";

   // Image path
  $image_path = "{$dir}/{$file}";

  $thumbnail_ext = pathinfo($thumbnail_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $image_ext = pathinfo($image_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

If you change path only of the `$dir` variable, you change `$thumbnail_path` and also `$image_path`.